# MySQL updates a different number

Tags: mysql, database

```
update profiles_profiles set unconfirmed_phone=2222222222 where id = 1;


mysql> select * from profiles_profiles\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               id: 1
          user_id: 1
            phone: NULL
unconfirmed_phone: 2147483647
```

For some reason , my update doesn't work with "2222222222".  However, it works with 1111111111.

MySQL always updates all the other fields, but it changes unconfirmed_phone to 2147483647, every single time.

```
mysql> desc profiles_profiles;
+-------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id           | int(11)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| phone             | int(11)  | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| unconfirmed_phone | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |


*************************** 8. row ***************************
           Name: products_products
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 0
 Avg_row_length: 0
    Data_length: 16384
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 16384
      Data_free: 5242880
 Auto_increment: 1
    Create_time: 2013-04-11 05:23:31
    Update_time: NULL
     Check_time: NULL
      Collation: utf8_general_ci
       Checksum: NULL
 Create_options: 
        Comment:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just means that the new value you want to update the current value simply overflowed. The maximum allowable value of `signed int` is `2147483647`.

Sometimes the data type for phone number can simply be `varchar` since others saved it with symbols like `(, ), -`

Excerp from the manual,

> The maximum value depends on the system. 32 bit systems have a maximum
>   signed integer range of -2147483648 to 2147483647. So for example on
>   such a system, intval('1000000000000') will return 2147483647. The
>   maximum signed integer value for 64 bit systems is
>   9223372036854775807.